# How to get the day of year in ruby?

Tags: ruby, datetime, date

What is the best way to get the day of the year for any specific date in Ruby?

For example: `31/dec/2009` should return `day 365`, and `01/feb/2008` should return `day 32`

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Basically (shown here in [irb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interactive_Ruby_Shell)):

```
>> require 'date'

>> Date.today.to_s
=> "2009-11-19"

>> Date.today.yday()
=> 323
```

For any date:

```
>> Date.new(y=2009,m=12,d=31).yday
=> 365
```

Or:

```
>> Date.new(2012,12,31).yday
=> 366
```

@see also: Ruby [Documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html)

Comment: Cool that you show that yday is not great for comparison across leap years after February :)

Answer (score 3):

Use `Date.new(year, month, day)` to create a `Date` object for the date you need, then get the day of the year with `yday`:

```
>> require 'date'
=> true
>> Date.new(2009,12,31).yday
=> 365
>> Date.new(2009,2,1).yday
=> 32
```

Answer (score 1):

[`Date#yday`](http://Ruby-Doc.Org/ruby-1.9/classes/Date.html#M001460) is what you are looking for.

Here's an example:

```
require 'date'

require 'test/unit'
class TestDateYday < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def test_that_december_31st_of_2009_is_the_365th_day_of_the_year
    assert_equal 365, Date.civil(2009, 12, 31).yday
  end
  def test_that_february_1st_of_2008_is_the_32nd_day_of_the_year
    assert_equal 32, Date.civil(2008, 2, 1).yday
  end
  def test_that_march_1st_of_2008_is_the_61st_day_of_the_year
    assert_equal 61, Date.civil(2008, 3, 1).yday
  end
end
```

Comment: I like the use of tests as examples +1

Answer (score 1):

You can use time without importing anything:

```
Time.new(1989,11,30).yday
```

or for now:

```
Time.now.yday
```

Comment: This should be the best main answer.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do something with   [`civil_to_jd(y, m, d, sg=GREGORIAN)`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Date.html)